# How can I reverse direction of this AC brushed motor?

Tags: motor, ac

Is it possible to reverse the direction of this universal motor I have extracted from a circular saw?

Here is a picture of the stator:

[image]

Comment: Are the stator and rotor in series or parallel? You need to reverse the direction/polarity of one of them.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure to understand, what should be in serie or parallel between the stator and the rotor ?

Comment: If I inverse brush wiring by wiring the left brush with the right winding, will it inverse polarity of the stator ? I have an hard time figuring this out due the perpetual polarity switch in AC current ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do to reverse the motor is this:

[image]

You cut the wires to the brushes at the spots indicated by black lines, then reconnect the brushes to the coils as shown by the red and blue lines.

Normally, each brush is connected to the coil closest to it.  You reconnect it so that each brush is connected to the coil opposite it.  Electrically, it is pretty simple.

Practically, however, it will be difficult.

There are crimped connections between the coil wires and the brushes.  You'd think you could just cut the coil wires and solder in some insulated wire to make the new connections.

The problem is that many such motors use aluminum wire in the coils.  Aluminum wire is very difficult to solder - that's why there are crimped connections in the motor.

You'd have to cut the wires and use crimp connectors for the rewiring.  It's not impossible, it's just not something that most folks will be able to do.  You need a good crimping tool and crimps made for the proper wire gauge.

---

I discovered the hard way that such motors use aluminum wiring while [reversing a sewing machine motor.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/universalmotor) When I did the first one, I had no trouble.  Later, I did another one and fiddled with the wires too much, causing one of the coil wires to break just below the crimp.  I thought it'd be no problem to solder it back together.  Once I go the lacquer insulation off of the coil wire, I found it was aluminum wire.  I could not get solder to stick to it.  There are special solders and fluxes for aluminum wire, but I didn't have any and the regular solder and flux I had didn't work.

---

An alternative to electrically reversing such a motor is to mount it so that you get the proper rotation direction.

Sewing machine motors are usually mounted so that the motor is behind the support column, out of the way.  You can mount them so that they stick out to the right of the handwheel instead.  The motor is kind of in the way and covers won't fit anymore, but from the point of view of the machine the motor rotates in the opposite direction.  Most sewing machines rotate counterclockwise, so most available replacement motors run counterclockwise.  There are some few oddball machines that run clockwise, though.  For those, you either reverse them electrically (which I prefer) or you mount them "the wrong way around" to mechanically reverse them.

Maybe you can mount your motor differently in whatever device you are building instead of electrically reversing it.

Comment: I marked your as answer cause your quick drawing was the solution. All answer where good though. I finally cutted the wire to undo 1 turn on each coil to have enough lenght to reverse the brushes wiring. Then crimped them back. Motor is now turning in the correct direction. Important note, my collector is flat (not angled) and brushed were perfectly symetrical.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a universal motor which is a series wound motor. You will need to swap the connections to the brushes.

There are two basic ways of wiring a motor series wound means that the field coil and rotor, supplied through the brushes, are connected in series. In a shunt wound motor they are connected in parallel.

As the motor is series wound when it is fed with AC both the field magnetic field and the rotor magnetic field change direction at the same time. This results in it rotating in one direction.

Comment: Thank for the informations !

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Reverse engineering the wiring.*

It appears that current flows from the mains, through the bottom coil, out onto the left brush, through the rotor, back through the blue brush and back to the mains supply through the top coil. That means the rotor and two coils are series connected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTDJHl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Wiring schematic.*

The wiring arrangement may be convenient for the manufacturer but it presents you with a little problem in trying to reverse the connections. You would have to desolder the field winding connections from the brushes, splice on some insulated extension wires and feed each to the other side, solder them to the opposite brush and secure them so that they can't touch the rotor.

First though, give us a photo of the other end of the motor to see if the brushes can be mounted on the other end. The manufacturer may have designed it to be easily reversible in manufacture for clockwise / anti-clockwise versions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the issue by switching the brushed. See comment above.